# How can I check ECS service creation logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I'm try to deploy a 'Hello World' Rails application to ECS.
I have some problems when create Service and I need to check logs to know what was wrong in my configuration. But I just found logs at:

- CloudFormation: just show status of the creation progress
- Service Health and Metrics tab: just show how many failed and completed
- Service Event tab

And that logs seem useless for me.

How can you check logs for ECS services? Thanks a lot!

[CloudFormation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHRG3.png)

[Service Health and metrics tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9evRn.png)

[Service events tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2WGP.png)

Comment: What about the "Logs" tab in that is visible in your "Service events tab" screenshot?

Comment: The logs tabs is empty @MarkB

Comment: Go to the "Tasks" tab, change the filter to "All" tasks instead of "Running", click on one of the stopped tasks, and see if you see any details of why it exited.

Comment: Oh, I found the logs, thanks a lot @MarkB